# Serenity BDD report generation

Tags: selenium, automation, serenity-bdd

We are trying to generate reports for our tests using serenity BDD. But we couldn't find anything to help with report generation.If anyone is familiar with this,Please suggest any simple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a report you need to use `apply plugin: 'net.serenity-bdd.aggregator'` plugin in your build.gradle file. Also while executing your project use `gradlew clean test aggregate` command from your command line.
After execution you will find index.html report under `\target\site\serenity`

[image]

Comment: @Femi Togun: Would you kind enough to accept my answer and hit upvote buutton

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Groovy MarkUpBuilder and create customized reports for your use case. Basically, you'll need to create a markup builder instance in Groovy as below :

```
def xmlWriter = new FileWriter(file("${project.buildDir}/index.html"))
def xmlMarkup = new MarkupBuilder(xmlWriter)
```

Create custom tags using below sytax :

`xmlMarkup.myCustomTag("Lorem Ipsum")`

which will produce :

`<myCustomTag>Lorem Ipsum</myCustomTag>`

So, for a syntax like `xmlMarkup.h1("Lorem Ipsum")` you'll get the output as `<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>`

Then you can just create a gradle task which parses all the test outputs (xml or json) into HTML.

I had written an article about that in the past which you can [find here](https://medium.com/@ishabbi/generating-html-reports-for-your-test-runs-via-gradle-the-easy-way-aa4d8860d18c)

Comment: The question is about serenity-bdd report configuration, not gradle reports in general.